# Example for using FormView to update with data binding?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, formview

I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/updating-deleting-and-creating-data) on asp.net.

It shows how to use FormView to Insert, but not to Update.  FormView seems very poorly documented.  All the examples I could find use SqlDataSource, not model binding.

In this case, I would like to use FormView on the same page instead of going off to a different page all together.  Quite confused about how to populate it with a single record, but the DataSource has to be a list of some kind. Isn't it supposed to be used to display and edit one record?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind record to FormView like this:

```
var oneRecord = GetRecordById(recordId);
var list = new List<Record> {oneRecord};
formView.DataSource = list;
formView.DataBind();
```

for editing, you need to write this line in codebehind:

```
formView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
```

Then you will be able to edit, but you must define `<EditItemTemplate/>` and `UpdateMethod` in your `FormView`.

If you don't need some special formatting, you can also try `DetailsView`.

Comment: I am trying use SelectMethod of a FormView. That appears to take a single instance.  I tried to have functions associated with UpdateMethod, InsertMethod, and DeleteMethod, but it won't let me use them unless selectMethod is used.